# HTML Form with Sendemail

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I can’t figure out where the problem comes from! The mail() is working perfectly (I already tested it with a simple php file) but my form doesn’t send any email!

HTML

```
  <section id="contact">
    <div id="google-map" class="wow fadeIn" data-latitude="35.7777622" data-longitude="10.8285004" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="400ms"></div>
    <div id="contact-us" class="parallax">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="heading text-center col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>Send a message</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Type your message" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send</button>
                </div>
              </form>   
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">                           
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </section><!--/#contact-->
```

main.js

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Progress...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thanks for your message</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

sendemail.php

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'MyEmail@RemovedFor.privacy';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

Could you please help me figuring out the problem? When I add a simple mail('MyEmail@RemovedFor.privacy', 'My Subject', 'message') to the sendemail.php file, every time the form is submitted, I receive an email! But I never receive the mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

Thank you very much

Comment: Don't use the error suppression operator (@) as it hides error messages that may be helpful in debugging your code. You should also always write your code so it does not generate any PHP errors including notices.

Answer (score 1):

You are spoofing the From header based on the user's input. Don't do this.

The From header of an email message must accurately represent the sender of the email message -- if you insert another value into this header, many mail servers will reject your mail or flag it as spam, as the resulting message will fail [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and/or [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) checks.

Use a From header which accurately represents the source of the message. For instance, if your web site is `example.com`, set the From header as `From: webmaster@example.com`. Include the email address and name set by the user either in the body of the message, or in a `Reply-To` header.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working! Now I receive the email but unfortunately, I receive empty message and empty subject (although I am sure I have added one). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think Headers needs to be a string.

```
$headers  = '';
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() . "\r\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You should also filter $_POST

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

I think you also need to send the data through the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  type: "POST",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But unfortunately I receive emails but empty emails, I tried your ajax request but it's still the same!